# Getting a key error while formatting a stringified dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Line of code:

```
data = '{"username": {u}, "password": {p}}'.format(u=user_name, p=password)
```

I just want to insert variables `user_name` and `password` inside the stringified dict above in the places `u` and `p` resp.

Error:

```
data = '{"username": {u}, "password": {p}}'.format(u=user_name, p=password)
KeyError: '"username"'
```

I also tried with:
`data = f'\{"username": {user_name}, "password": {password}\}'`

But that didn't seem to work.

Any other way to tackle this?

Comment: you want to make a string representation of a dict?

Comment: I just want to insert variables inside the stringified dict. (in places of 'u' and 'p'

Comment: `data = '{{"username": {u}, "password": {p}}}'.format(u=user_name, p=password)` (see answer from @Masklinn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to include `{}` in an f-string we simply double them up.

So the following gives the output you want.

```py
>>> username = "foo"
>>> password = "bar"
>>> f'{{"username": {username}, "password": {password}}}'
'{"username": foo, "password": bar}'
```

Comment: You should really use single quotes as string delimiters so you don't have to escape all the double quotes in the string.

Comment: I've ammended the answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Got to know something new. Thanks.
 ```f'{{ "username": "{user_name}", "password": "{password}"}}'```

Comment: ty for _`double quotes`_

Answer (score 3):

You need to *double up* the braces to escape them in [str.format patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Though the code is odd, why are you trying to insert stuff into a stringified pseudo-dict instead of stringifying the final dict e.g. `json.dumps({'username': u, 'password': p})`?

Because here the content of your data items will be "raw" e.g. assuming `user_name="billy bob"` and `password="george"` you're doing to end up with

```
'{"username": billy bob, "password": george}'
```

which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I just want to pass this ```data``` variable into a ```requests.post('link', data=data)``` and the data consists of credentials username and password needed to hit an external API. So was trying to figure out if there is something we can do in shorter lines and edit the variable in such a way without using  json library

Comment: @AjayBhagchandani Just to make sure: Have you seen the example in the `requests` documentation: `r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})`. There `data` is passed as a dictionary, not as a string that looks like a botched representation of a dictionary.

Comment: @AjayBhagchandani there's no reason not to use the json library built into the stdlib, but here you can just use `requests.post(..., json=data)`.

Comment: @Matthias that's going to form-encode the dict, not send it as json data. It's pretty rare for "external API" to use form-encoded inputs, though it happens.

Comment: The documentation gives an example for that too: `payload = {'some': 'data'}` followed by `r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))`.

Comment: @Matthias and just the next paragraph it suggests `requests.post(url, json=payload)` instead.

Comment: @Matthias it's giving me ```JSON parse error``` when I try to pass ```data``` as a dictionary in my case. I'm getting the proper response from API only when my ```data``` is a stringified dict.